# How to send document library document from one group to another group people by using designer workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

Need some help..

My requirement is: we have three groups 1.Requestor,2.Aprrovers 3.vendors.
In Requestor group, there are number of persons and every one can have permissions to create contract(DocumentLibrary document). Here one Requestor can see the contracts created by him only not by others created docs in the same DocumentLibrary. -- How to set it?

For that better to take List item level permissions or UserProfile or anyother??

And secondly , how can I send this document with attachment(by clkickng on DocumentLibrary submit button) to other group(approvers) for approving through designer workflow. ??

Note: im using OOTB .
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 : To set item level permission

Use "Replace List Item Permissions" action in SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow. Please refer the following links for implementation details...

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2/

http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2010/03/configure-item-level-permissions-for-document-libraries-part-2/

http://nikpatel.net/2014/05/11/handy-sharepoint-designer-workflow-tip-configure-item-level-permissions/

If you are using SharePoint 2013 then you have to create a "SharePoint 2010 workflow" platform type workflow to use this action in SharePoint Designer.

2. Send document as Email Attachment

SharePoint Designer does not provide any OOB action to send email with attachment...the workaround is to embed the document link into the email body and send the email. Please refer to the following link for details...

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/204397.aspx

Codeplex have custom designer activity to support this feature but you need to install the solution in your server first to use it...please refer to the following link...

http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thats awesome Avijit. Thanks alot.
I heard UserProfile also will work for the same?

Comment: So, sending document with email is not possible with designer??
can't we use javascript with approval form? any idea??

Comment: Following blogs have demonstration of using REST with JQuery & SharePoint to send mail functionality... http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2014/07/03/sending-email-with-sharepoint-and-jquery.aspx

Comment: Another blog...                       http://maxslabyak.com/c-sharp/using-jquery-to-send-email-with-web-services/

Comment: I would not recomment item level permissions, performnce can degrade quickly

Comment: Thanks Avijit,, So according to designer workflow links above Do i have to send 2 urls to the group? one is for viewing document and another is for Approval/Rejection form.? right??

Comment: You are absolutely right Sir!!!

Comment: ohh!!what PirateEric? any other way to do the same ??

Comment: Hi @PirateEric ,, can you please suggest me that any other way to do item level permissions? thanks.

Comment: Folder level security, each user has a folder permissioned to them or just using a view where created by equals [me] if it is just a matter of abstracting away other peoples information.

Comment: You can provide the Current item : document link directly in the task form and then you need to pass the task link only to the approvers as they can find the respective doc links in respective tasks.